Let $H=\{\sigma\in S_n\mid 1\le\sigma(i) \le k\;\forall i=1,2,\cdots,k\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ and $H\cong S_k\times S_{n-k}$.
I have trouble completing this proof.

Let $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 < k < n.$ Let $H=\{\sigma \in S_n\mid 1 \leq \sigma(i) \leq k\; \forall i =1,2,\cdots,k\}.$ Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ and $H \cong S_k \times S_{n-k}$.

Here is what I have done so far:
First notice that $\epsilon \in H$, so $H$ is non empty.
Let $a,b \in H.$ Furthermore, let $x \in \{1,2,\cdots, k\}.$ Since $1 \leq b(x) \leq k,$ and
$1 \leq a(x) \leq k$ we see that $1 \leq a \circ b(x) \leq k.$
I dont know how to prove that there is an inverse element for every $a \in H.$
For the isomorphic part, I am using the theorem that if $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ where $$h_1h_2 = h_2h_1,\\
H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\},\\ G= H_1H_2. $$ Then we can say that $G \cong H_1 \times H_2.$
Let $a \in S_k$ and $b \in S_{n-k}.$ Since the intersection of the two sets must be the empty set, it follows that $a$ and $b$ are disjoint cycles and hence $a\circ b = b \circ a.$
From here I dont know how to proceed. I have the tools to solve this problem, but don't know how to use them.
Any help is appreciated.

$H_1 \cap H_2 \ne \emptyset$ (a group is never empty).

Then we can say that $\color{red}G \cong H_1 \times H_2.$

You can answer both questions simultaneously by noticing that $H$ is the image of some injective homomorphism $S_k\times S_{n-k}\to S_n$, which I leave to you to define.

For any $k\in I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $A_k:=\{1,\dots,k\}$ and $B_k:= I_n\setminus A_k$. Then your $H$ can be rephrased as:
$$H:=\{\sigma\in S_n\mid\sigma(A_k)=A_k\}$$
Like any stabilizer, $H$ is a subgroup of the parent group ($S_n$, in this case). Now, if $\sigma\in H$, then $\sigma_{|A_k}\in S_k$ and $\sigma_{|B_k}\in\operatorname{Sym}(B_k)\cong S_{n-k}$.
Lemma. The map $f\colon H\to S_k\times\operatorname{Sym}(B_k)$ defined by:
$$\sigma\mapsto f(\sigma):=(\sigma_{|A_k},\sigma_{|B_k})$$
is an isomorphism.
Proof.

Injectivity:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\sigma_{|A_k},\sigma_{|B_k})=(\tau_{|A_k},\tau_{|B_k}) &\Longrightarrow (\sigma_{|A_k}=\tau_{|A_k})\wedge(\sigma_{|B_k}=\tau_{|B_k}) \\
&\Longrightarrow \sigma=\tau \\
\end{alignat}
Surjectivity: for every $(\alpha,\beta)\in S_k\times\operatorname{Sym}(B_k)$, we get $(\alpha,\beta)=f(\sigma)$, where $\sigma:=ext_\alpha\circ ext_\beta$, being $ext_\alpha$ (resp. $ext_\beta$) the extension of $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$) to $I_n$  via the identity map of $B_k$ (resp. $A_k$).
Homomorphism: for every $\sigma,\tau\in H$ (hence $\sigma\tau\in H$):
\begin{alignat}{1}
f(\sigma\tau) &= ((\sigma\tau)_{|A_k},(\sigma\tau)_{|B_k}) \\
&= (\sigma\tau_{|A_k},\sigma\tau_{|B_k}) \\
&= (\sigma_{|A_k}\tau_{|A_k},\sigma_{|B_k}\tau_{|B_k}) \\
&= (\sigma_{|A_k},\sigma_{|B_k})(\tau_{|A_k},\tau_{|B_k}) \\
&= f(\sigma)f(\tau) \\
\end{alignat}

$\Box$
So, $H\cong S_k\times\operatorname{Sym}(B_k)\cong S_k\times S_{n-k}$.

Generalization. For every partition $\{1,2,\dots,n\}=A_1\sqcup A_2\sqcup\dots\sqcup A_N$ (whence $n=\sum_{i=1}^N|A_i|$), the subgroup:
$$H:=\{\sigma\in S_n\mid \forall i=1,\dots,N:\sigma(A_i)=A_i\}\le S_n$$
is isomorphic to:
$$\prod_{i=1}^N S_{|A_i|}$$
